# In Borderlands, what if my character is past level 50 and then I play without the DLC installed?

Tags: borderlands

In Borderlands, say I play with the Secret Armory DLC installed and rank up past level 50. Then, I move my game save to another Xbox 360 that doesn't have the DLC, sign in with the same gamertag, and try to load the save.

Assuming I last saved in an area in the main game and not one of the DLC levels, and have the latest title update installed. What happens? Does it prevent me from playing, lower me to level 50, or allow me to continue in the main game at, say, level 55 without the DLC anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but I would guess it won't allow you to play.

Character information is most likely stored in the game save, which was probably altered somehow by the DLC, so I guess a game without the DLC won't be able to read it properly.

I would test it for a more "official" answer, but I don't own the game.

Comment: I have seen this happen in other games when savegames transfer. You get a notification that the save game has DLC data and you do not have DLC installed.